# OpenShift Status 404 - Tomcat local working fine

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, openshift

I have been trying without success so far.... Any help is appropriated.

1. I created a sample webservice and deployed locally and is working fine.
2. I have an OpenShift account with tomcat and deployed the package through eclipse. Build is good and Deployment is successful.
3. My calls to the webservice are returning with **503** error.
4. The haproxy-status page shows local-gear is down. after research for almost a day, I have removed the line "**option httpchk GET /**" from **haproxy/conf/haproxy.cfg**. Now the local-gear is up and running.
5. Now my requests are returning with **404** error code.

Any help is appreciated as I am sort of stuck here.

Thanks,

```
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://server.tna.scan.com/";
// Webservice URL - WSDL File location   
//private static String URL = "http://192.168.2.5:8080/TNAService/services/TNAService?WSDL";
private static String URL = "http://myapp-mydemain.rhcloud.com:8000/TNAService/services/TNAService?WSDL";
// SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "";
```

########HERE IS THE ERROR

06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086): org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 404
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:237)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at com.scan.tna.service.WService.invokeHelloWorldWS(WService.java:43)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at com.scan.tna.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:162)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at com.scan.tna.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-04 20:01:43.406: W/System.err(26086):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-04 20:01:43.416: I/System.out(26086): Yes Received

#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should Check **pom.xml and web.xml**.. Don't built your jar files in Built path it occurs **503 error**.. It is a maven format so built your jar  in **pom.xml**. 
For maven  check this url. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.30

And check the mapping in **web.xml**. i think this is the problem. because it only make 404 error. check and tell

Comment: It was build from pom.xml only and deployed to the server from local  eclipse environment. When comes to web.xml, it is the same web.xml which is working in the local tomcat server. So do not know what to look for and change.

Comment: Will you pls tell me the url that shows 404 error..?

Comment: Added the code snippet above. The one with 192.168.2.5 is  working. Same code with rhclund is giving me 404

Comment: Try this...   `private static String URL = "https://myapp-mydemain.rhcloud.com/TNAService/services/TNAService?WSDL";
` or `private static String URL = "https://myapp-mydemain.rhcloud.com/TNAService?WSDL";`

Comment: All openshift url are https and Don't put port number in url.

Comment: Don't use **host name** like 192.00.00.00.. it only use in **mysql** only.. use only url..

Comment: I tried all that you have mentioned with no luck. Just for additional check, I added a dummy index.html in the root. I was able to access index.html  from local as well as rhc. But webservice only from local but not rhc. It got to be something silly........

Comment: Tried for the similar URLs and finally worked for "http://myapp-mydemain.rhcloud.com/services/TNAService?WSDL"

Comment: Yes correct.. I too want to said that.. ok i have lot of experience in **openshift**.. If you having any queries tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The URL I used in the local machine is

http://localhost.mydomain/TNAService/services/TNAService?WSDL

and the URL in the rhc is

http://myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/services/TNAService?WSDL

No idea why different URLs  on different machines but like mentioned above you have to either correct your web.xml or use different URLs.